# JavaScript - how to have a third "sub variable"

Tags: javascript, html, variables, random

okay, I forgot what the name for a variable list linked to a single variable already inside of a list is called, but just take a look:

```
function Models(Make) {
    var cars = {
        "Acura": ['Integra', 'NSX', 'RSX', ],
        "BMW": ['M3', ],
        "Buick": ['Regal', ],
        "Cadillac": ['CTS', ],
        "Honda": ['Accord', 'Civic', 'CR-Z', 'Prelude', ],
        "Mazda": ['3', 'MX-5', 'MX-6', 'RX-7', 'RX-8', ],
        "Mini": ['Cooper', ],
        "Nissan": ['240SX', '350Z', 'Fairlady', 'GT-R', 's13', 's14', 's15', ],
        "Toyota": ['Celica', 'MR2', 'Supra', ],
    };
    var holder = cars[Make]
    var Model = holder[Math.floor(Math.random() * holder.length)];
    return Model;
}

function main() {
    var Makes = [
            'Acura',
            'BMW',
            'Buick',
            'Cadillac',
            'Honda',
            'Mazda',
            'Mini',
            'Nissan',
            'Toyota',
    ];
    var Make = Makes[Math.floor(Math.random() * Makes.length)];
    var Model = Models(Make);
    var Out = Make + " " + Model;
    return Out;
}

document.write(main());
```

I would like to add a third class after the model of the vehicle (such as Mini Cooper "S" or Honda Civic "Del Sol"), how would be the best way for me to go about doing that?

Comment: Do you search for the term *property*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cars` object contains a number of properties that are all `Array`s, and these `Array`s are indexed, containing `String`s.

If you want to store more than just a string (the model), then you'll have to change that to an array or object:

```
var cars = {
    "Acura": [
        {
            base: 'Integra'
            submodals: ['S', 'Coupe', 'Si']
        },
        {
            base: 'NSX',
            submodels: ['A', 'B', 'C']
        },
        // ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: That looks a bit overcomplicated to me. Why not just use an object again?

Comment: But how do I utilize the submodels?  How can I call them?

Comment: @Bergi -- definitely possible. It all depends on how Garret wants the data represented.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function that can take an arbitrarily deep nested object as an argument. Then structure it like this:

```
var cars = {
    "Acura": {
        "Integra": ['S', 'Coupe', 'Si'],
        "NSX": "",
        "RSX": ""
    },
    "BMW": ['M3'],
    "Buick": ['Regal'],
    "Cadillac": ['CTS'],
    "Honda": {
        "Accord": "",
        "Civic": ["Del Sol"],
        "CR-Z": "",
        "Prelude": ""
    },
    "Mazda": ['3', 'MX-5', 'MX-6', 'RX-7', 'RX-8'],
    "Mini": {
        "Cooper": ["S"]
    },
    "Nissan": ['240SX', '350Z', 'Fairlady', 'GT-R', 's13', 's14', 's15'],
    "Toyota": ['Celica', 'MR2', 'Supra']
};
// (and notice: no trailing commas!)
```

Then you can recursively select a random model:

```
function main() {
    return getRandom(cars).join(" ");
}
function getRandom(o) {
    if (o instanceof Array)
        return o.slice(~~(Math.random()*o.length), 1); // a random item in an array
    // else
    var props = Object.keys(o),
        r = props[ ~~(Math.random()*props.length) ],
        p = o[r];
    if (typeof p == "object") {
        var res = getRandom(p); // recurse
        res.unshift(r);
        return res;
    } // else
    return [ r ]; // an array literal with the random key
}
```